# Uploading the file for a SharePoint SocialAttachment when creating a SocialPost?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, upload, attachment

I am interested in writing code to create a new SocialPost on SharePoint 2013 and include an image attachment. The code for creating the post and referencing the attachment is straight-forward (and well-documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn232144%28v=office.15%29.aspx)), but the part about uploading the file itself seems to be undocumented.

The out-of-the-box newsfeed appears to initially add files to a list called "User Photos" that lives directly under the My Site root. (If you go to (my site server)/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx you'll see the list there.)  The photos are placed in a "Feed Attachments" folder. (I'm assuming this requires elevated privileges, btw?) However, after that, it appears that they are copied to a location under the individual's My Site -- e.g.,  (my site server)/personal//Lists/PublishedFeed/Attachments.  Oddly enough, you can't even see this list in the Site Contents listing.

I would happily write code to upload the files to one of these lists, but it's unclear what the "right" way to do it is. Furthermore, the structure of these lists is quite complex, and as far as I can tell the fields are not documented.

Of course, I have the option of uploading the files elsewhere -- say a Picture Library of my choosing. That seems like a lame workaround, though. Also, the default list seems to have metadata related to the Post it was attached to, which I assume is used for cleanup if the Post was ever deleted? Seems like I would want that to work.

Does anyone know the "right" way to upload the image file and the proper location for it?

--

UPDATE: I recently noticed that there is a one line reference to the [/_api/SP.Social.SocialFeedManager/CreateImageAttachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.server.social.spsocialfeedmanager.createimageattachment%28v=office.15%29.aspx) REST endpoint in the documentation, but no reference examples. I've tried without success to POST data to this, but I can't get it to work. It keeps telling me that I didn't supply the "name" parameter... but I am including it. I'm pretty sure the request is formed correctly.

After finding this, I also tried looking at the client-side object model implementation of the same thing - there's a createImageAttachment() function on the SP.Social.SocialFeedManager object - and I got closer, but it's telling me that there are invalid characters in my imageData. I've tried sending it as raw data (that I got from a JS FileReader) and also tried Base64 encoding it. When I encode it, I don't get errors about invalid characters, but it also says I didn't pass and imageData.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you are not to positioning your stream to the beginning, after read it. After you read the file into the stream and before you call the method CreateImageAssignment you have to position to the beginning of the stream:

```
stream.Seek(0. SeekOrigin.Begin)
```